# MySQL query to retrieve only keywords using title case from text

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a table with a column in a database table called `KeywordText` which currently contains text in lower case, e.g. the word `global`.

However, if I now need to include keywords in title or upper case, these must be distinct from the lower case keywords, so `Global` is not the same as `global`.

Typically, a MySQL `SELECT * FROM Keyword WHERE KeywordText = 'global'` returns two results, i.e. so `Global` and `global`.

But can anyone suggest a way to return only `Global`? I don't think that including `LIKE BINARY` in the query will help because it will return other unigram or bigram keywords such as `Global networking`.

Apologies for any duplication of previous questions.

Comment: There's some information and approaches in the mysql docs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a case sensitive query you need to do it Binary so that it compares each byte of information. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE BINARY `column` = 'value'
```